# Strange symbol in UEFI boot order instead of "Ubuntu" - is everything ok?

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-order

I wiped my SSD and installed Ubuntu from a flash drive. After restarting multiple times, since the computer was always restarting, I decided to boot up without my flash drive plugged in and it worked.

I opened BIOS to take a look at the boot order there was kind of a mesh character that showed up instead of something like "Ubuntu". I then decided to click on load default features to see what happened and saw `<null string>` below the boot order sign.

Since I was to afraid to let it boot up like that I decided to revert the changes. The computer still works fine with this strange thing but I was wondering if everything went OK.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To be honest, your question looks unclear to me. First you said "things messed up" and in the end you said "the computer still works fine". Is the issue solved? Or if not, what is the exact issue? Is it related to naming in boot menu?

Comment: i mean, kinda yeah. I don't know if it's a big deal. I was just anxious if i did a correct installation of ubuntu since it doesn't mention ssd or something idk. but i guess if it ain't broke, don't fix it

Answer (score 1):

I found solution of this problem, first use next command:

```
sudo cfdisk /dev/sdX
```

and set [ Type ] > EFI System

next create a new record in boot

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Ubuntu" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
```