# Change OS name in BIOS boot priority

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, bios, acer, boot-repair

I have Ubuntu and Windows installed. Ubuntu is not properly displayed in the BIOS boot priority order. Can anyone suggest how to fix this from the terminal or any other way other than BCDEdit (Windows)?

Here is an image of BIOS from Acer laptop.

[image: BIOS boot priority]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange symbol in UEFI boot order instead of "Ubuntu" - is everything ok?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155245/strange-symbol-in-uefi-boot-order-instead-of-ubuntu-is-everything-ok)

Comment: My understanding is that a Duplicate question must have a vote of at least +1. See help "A duplicate requires a single vote from a user who has earned a gold tag … Questions with vote to close as a duplicate will also list each possible duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I found solution of this problem, first use next command:

```
sudo cfdisk /dev/sdX
```

and set [ Type ] > EFI System

next create a new record in boot

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Ubuntu" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
```